What's this weird pixellated image I often see at the top of Microsoft Office windows?

The image is such poor quality it doesn't seem intentional. It looks more like marks on a screen. What's the purpose/intention of this?

The purpose is just to change the appearance of the Microsoft Office applications. You can change it here: File > Options > General > Office background. This particular background appears to be 'Clouds'.

Thanks. But it's not a background. It only appears sometimes. And it's only in the header. Also why the very low quality pixelated image? It looks awful.

Well, the setting is called background so I suppose that's what it is. As to why the low quality, we can't look into the artist's head, so your guess is as good as mine.
